# Passing html input value to java code on same page (JSP)

Tags: html, jsp

I am currently using this code:

**< input type="text" id="employeeid" name="employeeid" value="${c.employee_id}">**

What i wanted to do is pass the value of employeeid to my java code on the same jsp page

**< % int empid = (value of employeeid) % >**

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```jsp
< % int empid = c.employee_id % >
```

If you're trying to make your page dynamic based on what the user enters, you'll either need javascript or an AJAX call to do it.

Comment: I got the value ${c.employee_id} from items {employeeid} || <c:forEach var="c" items="${employeeid}">

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't do it in same `jsp` page. Because `jsp` is processed in a web-container and converted to `html` code then it is forwarded to web-browser with the data already filled in it.

You have to involve two `jsp` pages for achieving this task by `<%= request.getParameter("..."); %>`on the second `jsp` page.

Please take a look here [JSP Architecture](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_architecture.htm) and head over to JSP Processing point num 5

Answer (score 0):

What i've done is this, i've created a servlet that will get the parameter value on "post" and edited this line

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int studid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("student_id"));
}
```